# Supported screen resolution for my LCD display not shown in Windows 10 options

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution, external-display

My LCD display (LG model:ips225xt) clearly works with 1920x1080, Windows 10 shows some supported resolutions, except this one. I'm connecting my laptop (DELL model:vostro 1520) through VGA to the display.

Comment: Do you have the correct driver installed for your video card?

Comment: If the screen is is mirrored mode, then it will use the laptop screens res. You have two options. Use extended monitor mode, or disable the power settings for the lid, and close it.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator According to the Dell driver setup, a newer driver is already installed